# Use CSS transition for bootstrap column

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am pretty newb with CSS and very newb with CSS transitions.

We have two sibling divs like so:

```
<div ng-class="rightSidebarOpen ? 'col-sm-8' : 'col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1'>

</div>

<div ng-class="rightSidebarOpen ? 'col-sm-4' : 'hidden'>

</div>
```

so when the rightSidebarOpen boolean is toggled to true, the css changes and the right sidebar becomes visible; likewise when rightSidebarOpen is toggled to false, the right sidebar becomes hidden.

However, the transition is so fast, it's not user friendly. How can I use a simple CSS transition to "open" and "close" the right sidebar given the situation? No idea how to do this!

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Also what's the visual layout of the page? I see that even when the sidebar is closed the other container doesn't stretch to full page width (only 10/12)

Comment: Yeah we are using 10 instead of 12 - we are using Bootstrap v3.3.7.

Comment: Are you transitioning to a static height or to a dynamic height? If the height you are animating to is static then it should be no problem with a css transition. If its a dynamic height when it opens you might have to use javascript to animate. BTW, using the class `hidden` will never allow for a transition to happen, because it's style is `display: none !important;` which will always hide it immediately.

Comment: the height of the two panels is basically static, I want to transition both widths right, because the widths are what changes. Good point WRT to hidden property, that makes sense.